# pandas Update dataframe after lambda operation

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Presently doing an Pandas operation with .apply() function.

```
fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'EQ']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[1])/100))

fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'DB']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[0])/100))

fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'LQ']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[2])/100))
```

each code is modifying certain collection of rows, now how do update the main dataframe ,

i tried something like this:

```
fund_table['fund_weight'] = fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'EQ']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[1])/100))
fund_table['fund_weight'] = fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'DB']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[0])/100))
fund_table['fund_weight'] = fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'LQ']['fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[2])/100))
```

but it is failing, all the values of the column 'fund_weight' are changing to **Nan**

what is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign to `fund_weight`, you overwrite whatever the column previously held, so then the next line is working with the wrong data.

Furthermore, when you filter based on fund_class, you create a *smaller* dataframe. `fund_table[fund_table.fund_class == 'EQ']['fund_weight']` is smaller than fund_table, so the series produced by your `apply` is smaller. When you try to assign this series to the whole dataframe, pandas fills in the missing values with NaN.

As a result your first line turns every row of `fund_weight` into NaN, *except* the rows where `fund_class` equals 'EQ'. Your next line filters all the rows where `fund_class` equals 'EQ', so it only sees NaN values, and now all of `fund_weight` is NaN.

You want something more like:

```
def calc_new_weight(row):
    if row['fund_class'] == 'EQ':
        overall_wt = overall_wts[1]
    elif row['fund_class'] == 'DB':
        overall_wt = overall_wts[0]
    elif row['fund_class'] == 'LQ':
        overall_wt = overall_wts[2]
    return row['fund_weight'] * overall_wt / 100
fund_table['fund_weight_calc'] = fund_table.apply(calc_new_weight, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc`:

```
fund_table.loc[fund_table.fund_class == 'EQ', 'fund_weight'] = fund_table.loc[fund_table.fund_class == 'EQ', 'fund_weight'].apply(lambda x: ((x*overall_wts[1])/100))
# ...
```

However, this might be better rewritten as a groupby:

```
wts = dict(zip(["DB", "EQ", "LQ"], overall_wts))
fund_table.groupby("fund_class").apply(lambda x: x * wts[x.name] / 100)
```

Comment: i couldnt get the groupby to work, error occured, so i used the loc method, but what is x.name in groupby method...

Comment: @Zaiku197212 x.name returns 'EQ' for the EQ group.